# Solve the inequality $|x^2-3x-15|<2x^2-x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, absolute-value

I wish to solve the inequality

> $$|x^2-3x-15|<2x^2-x$$

I have tried to solve this inequality in this way

Let $|x^2-3x-15|=f(x)$ and $2x^2-x = g(x)$ then solve for $f(x)<g(x)$ and then put the answer in sign chart and check if the intervals satisfy this inequality $f(x)\ge 0$ and solve for $f(x)>-g(x)$ and check if intervals satisfy this inequality $f(x)<0$.

But in second one the answer come up to be $(-\infty,-5/3)\cup (3,+\infty)$ and if we choose for example $(-3)$ it doesn't satisfy the inequality $f(x)<0$.

Is the way that I am solving wrong if it's so can you please show me an accurate and general way of solving such inequalities.

Comment: Hi Ella, welcome to MSE! Please do consider using mathjax. I formatted a part of your post as an example. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The answer is right.

I like the following way.

It's equivalent to
$$-2x^2+x<x^2-3x-15<2x^2-x,$$ which gives
$$x^2+2x+15>0$$ and
$$3x^2-4x-15>0$$
and since $$x^2+2x+15=(x+1)^2+14>0,$$ which is true for all reals $x$ and
$$3x^2-4x-15=3x^2-9x+5x-15=(x-3)(3x+5),$$ we got the answer:
$$\left(-\infty,-\frac{5}{3}\right)\cup(3,+\infty).$$

I used the following fact.
$$|f(x)|<g(x)\Leftrightarrow-g(x)<f(x)<g(x).$$

Comment: But when i solved f(x)>-g(x) I found the intervals to be (-infinity, -5/3)U (3, infinity) and if I put (-3) from first interval it doesn satisfy f (x)<0

Comment: It's exactly which I got.

Comment: What do we use f(x)>=0 and f (x)<0 For?

Comment: I think it's very ugly and unnecessary.

Comment: But why we cannot solve question such that                    |(x+2)/(2x-3)|<3 in the same exact way?

Comment: It's $-3<(x+2)(2x-3)<3.$ Cases $(x+2)(2x-3)\geq0$ and $(x+2)(2x-3)<0$ the are unnecessary.

Comment: My question was actually abs((x+2)over(2x-3))<3 sorry for not using mathjax formatting because I am new

Comment: The way is the same.